# Android : is a width of 160dp equals to 100% of the screen width?

Tags: android, xml, layout

Here is the definition of dp unit : (if it is correct...)

Density-independent Pixels - an abstract unit that is based on the physical density of the screen. These units are relative to a 160 dpi screen, so one dp is one pixel on a 160 dpi screen.

So, is a width of 160dp equals to 100% of the screen width for any kind of screen ?

According to some tests I performed, it seems that it is not the case.

Am I wrong ? Is there something I don't understand ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  160 dp is 1 inch (or extremely close).  What they're saying is if you had a 160 dpi (dot per inch) device, then 1 pixel=1dp.  160 dpi was common in the early days of Android.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is 160dp equal to 1 inch for any screen density ? For example, is 160dp equal to 1 inch for a 320 dpi screen ? Thanks !

Comment: Yes.  That's why they made dp-  so you could have a constant physical size regardless on the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi dpi means density of pixels per inch  so 160 dpi means 160 pixels in one inch area.

Say length of device = 4 inch and breath of device = 3 inch
So the Area = 4*3 = 12 squreInches
We have pixel per square inch = 160 pixels
so total no of pixels in screen = 12 * 160

**The pixels in breath = 12 * 160 /4 = 480 Pixels
The pixels in length = 12 * 160 /3 = 640 pixels**

160dp in mdpi devices means 160 pixels

**so if you draw the line of 160dp, it will cover 1/3rd of screen.**

**because 160/480 = 1/3**

So please check and give your feed back.

For more information you can go through the following link.

[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android)

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/understanding-density-independence-in-android

Answer (score 0):

No. 1dp is 1px of a 160ppi screen. This means 160dp will be 1 inch exactly. 
No. Of dp in a screen can be found as:

`No. Of dp = (size(in px)/pixel density)*160`

no. Of pixels in 1 dp can be found as:

`no. Of pixels in a dp =pixel density/160.`

On 160ppi screen:
1px=160/160=1dp.

On 240ppi screen:
1px=240/160=1.5dp.

On 320ppi screen:
1px=320/160=2dp.